# PDF Thumbnailing with Google App Engine (Python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pdf

Is it possible, using the python version of google app engine, to create a thumbnail of a PDF file?

The goal is for the user to be able to upload a PDF, and see it represented as a thumbnail on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. This requires a PDF renderer, and to the best of my knowledge no such thing exists in pure-Python. You'll have to use an external service to generate thumbnails.

Answer (score 2):

You may be able to use Google's imaging services directly, since PDFs are essentially images and [PIL can do this](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm), though I haven't tried it.

If the direct approach doesn't work, you may be able to use the following process:

1. Save the PDF to the blobstore.
2. Open its link.
3. Obtain a snapshot of the displayed PDF using a service like http://www.websnapr.com/.
4. Save that generated image into your blobstore.

Comment: Your PIL link is dead, and when I tried to open a PDF in PIL it did not work. I think PIL can output PDFs, but not open them. (This was what I had tried before I came here).

Comment: Fixed the link; if PIL doesn't work directly, hopefully the process above does, or at least sparks some other ideas to achieve this.

Comment: The Image API doesn't support PDFs (they're not images), and what PIL and the Images API can do are distinct in any case.